# Could not connect to development server - react native error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, metro-bundler

I had a react native project that is working fine and I switched to another project which is also a react native project. When I came back to the development of the first project I ran the following commands. I use a physical device to debug.

1. `cd ./projectfolder`
2. `react-native start --reset-cache`
3. `react-native run-android` in another terminal

Now the following problems are there, I would like to know what are the causes.

- `react-native start` starts the Metro Bundler but it does not show the
  loading progress of the files after `react-native run-android`
  finishes. (Does not serve files)
- Still the application starts without any red screen. (How does this
  happen if the Metro Bundler has no progress shown?)
- Since the application starts I can shake the running device and try
  to enable the hot loading but it gives a error on the red screen.

  [image: Screenshot of the error]

(Sorry for the bad quality, I got this from internet. The same message is there on my physical device.)

I have tried the following methods.

- Clear the npm cache using `npm cache clean --force`.
- Make sure that the laptop and the mobile are on the same wifi.
- Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the manifest since there are Android 9 related changes as per most github answers.
- Uninstall the application and trying to run again.
- Restarting everything.
- Ran the bundle command and try but it will not help start the debugger.

Can I have any help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to start react-native node server as it gets turned on automatically, so you just need to write "react-native run-android"

Comment: Still the same error. I thought it didnt matter. This is more like the Metro Bundler is not discoverable when running.

Comment: Do you have "network_security_config.xml" with you in project? Suppose to be located under android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml .... withint he file you should have your computer's IP declared. Then on your device, shake the app, set your computer IP (eg, 192.168.1.190:8081) as well.

Comment: Can you please share image of your emulator in which you get error as this is not clearly visible? You can just do print screen and paste that image here

Comment: Deleting node-modules and npm installing it again maybe

Comment: @buddhiv try this: > watchman watch-del-all

Comment: @yeslam - This doesn't work. I the solution previously as well. No help!

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I checked this as well. didn't help.